# Format Text box for latitude issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, format

I am having issues defining a field in MySQL database and displaying it in a text box on a PHP form.

In regards to latitude and longitude in written format.

I have in the database the field, latitude which stores a value such as:  52° 18′ 29″ N
The structure for this field is 
type: varchar(50)
collation: utf8_unicode_ci

I have also tried type: text

The html for the text box is:

```
 <input type="text" name="latitude" size="40" 
 value="<? echo "$row[latitude]"?>">
```

When I call the form, the data looks like:
52° 18? 29? N

How would I change this so that it formats it as:  52° 18′ 29″ N

Should I store it differently in the database?

Comment: have you tried -> `value="<? echo htmlspecialchars("$row[latitude]") ?>"` http://php.net/htmlspecialchars or `value="<? echo htmlentities("$row[latitude]", ENT_QUOTES) ?>"` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Did you copy it from microsoft word? The double quote character on microsoft word may be a different character code in comparison with your charset. Try to update the double quote mannually(without copy and paste. Just type it)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Sean, your suggestions did not resolve the issue. Jose, I have been copying from geohack website (clicking on the geographic coordinates in wikipedia), so i'm copying it from an html website.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to bandaid fix the problem, this will do it:

```
<input type="text" name="latitude" size="40" 
 value="<? echo "str_replace('?','\'',$row[latitude]"?>">
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0aaab9d9141b6294e0b92cc976044c9d4726cdb